# React Router and redux auth token double render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

So i am using redux, dispatching a token if user logs in. Then I fetch the user's token and if it exists I set X routes available other wise, Y routes. Problem is that at every refresh, the App component renders twice. The first time it token is `null` second time token is `true`.

Well, why is it rendering twice?
Please answer with different approaches for the same action if you think its more efficient than that.

please, if you need more code, ask.

regards

code:

```
const App = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const token = useSelector((state) => state.auth.token);
    const onCheckAuth = useCallback(() => dispatch(checkAuth()), [dispatch]);

    useEffect(() => {
        onCheckAuth();
    }, [onCheckAuth]);

    const render = () => {
        if (token) {
            return (
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/hearing' component={Hearing} />
                    <Route path='/logout' component={Logout} />
                    <Route path='/' exact component={Dashboard} />
                    <Redirect to='/' />
                </Switch>
            );
        }

        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
                <Redirect to='/login' />
            </Switch>
        );
    };

    console.log(token);

    return <>{render()}</>;
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'll explain briefly why it is rendered twice.

When the app first loaded, the redux has initial state and the app dispatches checkAuth action. This is the first render.

Once the checkAuth is dispatched, the state of redux will be updated and it causes another render.

This why it is rendered twice.

Then I'll explain how to handle token in react App.

You should save token in Browser's local storage, not in the redux.

So when the app first loaded, token in local storage must be checked its existence and expiration. Then it's okay to save token to redux to be synced with token updates.
If it's an invalid token, then you need to refresh a new token.

Finally using functional component you don't need to define render() method.

It should be returned directly.

```
const App = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const token = useSelector((state) => state.auth.token);
    const onCheckAuth = useCallback(() => dispatch(checkAuth()), [dispatch]);

    useEffect(() => {
        onCheckAuth();
    }, [onCheckAuth]);

    if (token) {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/hearing' component={Hearing} />
                <Route path='/logout' component={Logout} />
                <Route path='/' exact component={Dashboard} />
                <Redirect to='/' />
            </Switch>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
                <Redirect to='/login' />
            </Switch>
        );
    }
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Yeah... of course... the initial state. I am actually saving on local storage. checkAuth checks if there is a token on local storage and set the token in the reducer auth. So i should check if there is a token directly on App component? And yeah, i know theres no need for the render method on functional components, its jsut a helper function with a bad name xd

Comment: the problem on this setup is that I cannot cause App component to refresh if it doesnt interact with reducer. If it does, it will always render twice and token will be null

Comment: Once the token is fetched, you should save it to the reducer so as to make the app sync with token update.

Comment: I did that. but initial state is always null by default. The thing that saved me was set on createStore a object setting the initial state:

`const store = createStore(reducer, { auth: { token: localStorage.getItem('token'), ...middlewares }});`

Comment: Please check out this reop. https://github.com/devopsmanta/reversi-frontend-react

Comment: sry bro, i just tried to clone and open on my end but got some hooks error, probably due to the version, i tried to dig the code and find about the initial state plus how you handle states, got some pretty good things but saw actions like LOGIN not being handled by reducer so I couldnt find what i was up to.

Answer (score 0):

It must render twice, as after first render the useEffect fires and that itself fires onCheckAuth which does a dispatch, then as a result of dispatch the react/redux notifies with the new state, so the second render happens.